# finite limite of integral in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

In the real domain, how can we decide if an integral is finite?

Example:  $$\int_0^\infty {dx\over x^a (1+x)}$$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x}$ this becomes the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 0):

The integral 
$$\int_{0+} {dx\over x^p}$$
integrates at zero iff $p < 1$.
The intergal
$$\int^\infty {dx\over x^p}$$
integrates at $\infty$ iff $p > 1$.
Your integral will integrate at neither end by the limit comparison test for improper integrals.

Comment: THanks a lot. This means that Alpha <= 1 and p= alpha +1 >=0. Soit alpha 0< alpha <= 1.  Alpha is a decimal number.

Comment: THanks a lot. This means that Alpha <= 1 and p= alpha +1 >=0. It becomes that the integrale is finite for  0< alpha <= 1.  Alpha is a decimal number. In complex analysis, Z=0 is a singularity. How to deal with decimal power with a pole? Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

When x close to $0$ compare the integrand with the function $ \frac{1}{x^{a}} $ and at infinity compare with the function $ \frac{1}{x^{a+1}} $.